# Unity URP Light2D, set target sorting layers programmatically

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, layer

Im working on a personal 2D game and have been looking into the Universal Pipeline Renderer and the Light2D object.

I currently have Light2D objects being generated dynamically during level generation which works fine except I cant find a way to set the Target Sorting Layers option programmatically I can only set them at runtime using the editor. Am I missing something obvious or is this not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This used to work in at least some of the experimental versions of URP using

```
[lightSpriteComponent].m_ApplyToSortingLayers
```

however, when it stopped being experimental, this stopped working and broke one of my projects.

A way to set this from code and a way to set the light's sprite at runtime like the old form

```
[lightSpriteComponent].lightCookieSprite = Sprite
```

would be fantastic. They both existed and you could probably go into the URP code and find a way to access them again but, as of now, I don't think it's possible without going to an older version.